# octopress index page

Tags: html, blogs, octopress

I have created an Octopress blog. My Blog page contains all my posts one by the other and I would like to change this.
I saw these pages: http://linuxmoz.com/, http://codingpraxis.com/ they contain a paragraph of each post and "Read On" button. I saw this specific template of such index page on other blogs.
How can I create this index page? In addition, is there any place where I can find "templates" for different pages (like about or contat me)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1**. Just using `<!-- more -->` in your post, Octopress will auto generate the "Read On" button.
**2**. It needs 2 steps to add the “About” page in Octopress:
  *1.Create the “about” page*

```
rake new_page["about"]
```

*2.Add the link*
  edit the file “source/_includes/custom/navigation.html”, by edding the 3rd line below:

```
<ul class="main-navigation">
  <li><a href="/">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="/blog/archives">Archives</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

After “rake generate”, the “source/about/index.markdown” will generate “public/about/index.html”, that’s the file whose content will be displayed to the browser.
[More Info](http://gangmax.me/blog/2012/05/04/add-about-page-in-octopress/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create additional index page. Inserting a  comment into 
your post will prevent the post content below this mark from being displayed on the index page for the blog posts, a "Continue →" button links to the full post.